# Docker Python : python-ldap error ldap.SERVER_DOWN

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ldap, python-ldap

I have some Django application that connect to a LDAP server.

On my machine everything work fine, but when I create docker container with python I am getting ldap.SERVER_DOWN error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 443, in simple_bind_s
    msgid = self.simple_bind(who,cred,serverctrls,clientctrls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 437, in simple_bind
return self._ldap_call(self._l.simple_bind,who,cred,RequestControlTuples(serverctrls),RequestControlTuples(clientctrls))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 329, in _ldap_call
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap/compat.py", line 44, in reraise
raise exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 313, in _ldap_call
result = func(*args,**kwargs)
ldap.SERVER_DOWN: {'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
```

What could be the problem?. 
I was googling for the answer, but nothing I found works for me.

As far as I know, it is not SSL problem (because otherwise would not work on local machine). It is probably not the problem with code,...

I have the same library installed and the same version (with pip freeze > requirements.txt and pip install -r requirements.txt)...

### EDIT:

I try to connect to the ldap server on new machine (Linux), without any certificate and it works. But if I deploy docker image on same machine has same error.

So I guess that docker is blocking my ldap connection,... pleas help

Comment: Why do you think it's not SSL? Container doesnt share certificates/keys with the host.

Comment: I don't think I use any certificates for it... but how do I check this?